# Excel VBA - Copy and Paste each cell Individually to another program

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA but know my way around it a bit (sorta). What I'm needing to do is get a Macro set to copy data in one cell, switch to another program (2315), enter "6", [ENTER], paste the data, [ENTER] switch back to Excel, select the next row, copy, switch, paste, switch, until it reaches the end of the column. This is what I have, which works for the first cell. I just need to figure out how to loop it until it reaches the end. Thanks for any help/suggestions!

```
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
AppActivate "2315"
Application.SendKeys "6~^V~"
Application.SendKeys "%{TAB}"
```

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this works, but you say it does and your question is about the loop. Here is the loop.

```
Dim R       As Long

For R = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(R, "A").Copy
    AppActivate "2315"
    Application.SendKeys "6~^V~"
    Application.SendKeys "%{TAB}"
Next R
```

For Excel's sake you don't need to select anything. The above code will loop through all the used cells in column A of the active tab. If your app "2315" needs the selection, add `Cells(R, "A").Select` before the copy instruction.

My doubt is based in the fact that you can't use VBA to send parameters to app "2315". This includes the instruction to "2315" to surrender control back to Excel and its VBA. Perhaps you have found such a way via the SendKeys. If so, the code will work. If not, it will get stuck after the first loop.

Logically, the code should run until AppActivate "2315", meaning the SendKeys are never sent until the other app has returned control. If that is what's going on there must be better ways to express whatever your two instructions get done. But that shouldn't be your immediate concern. If you can get "2315" to surrender control back to Excel with a simple command like *Enter*, and if the above macro really resumes work where it left off, most of your problem should be solved. This I hope for :-)

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. I actually took out the SendKeys altTab and it works like a charm. Not sure what you mean by not using VBA to send parameters to my other app, but either way, this is just what I needed and it works! Thanks so much for your help!